# Dual-boot loads Windows 8.1 first, and Ubuntu occasionally completely crashes

Tags: boot, dual-boot, crash

The title says it all really, but to give you some context, I only recently installed Ubuntu 14.10 on a [Lenovo Flex 15D laptop](http://www.staples.ca/en/Lenovo-59424917-Flex-2-Notebook-156-8GB-1TB/product_1148177_2-CA_1_20001), which came with Windows pre-installed. I've still been using Windows most of the time because in order for me to boot Ubuntu, I usually have to hold shift as I press restart, and tell Windows to load Ubuntu via a menu, on the next power-up. Then, even as I'm using Ubuntu, it will occasionally crash straight to a black screen as if I had just taken the battery out of the laptop.

I'm sure this has been a fairly common problem; what information can I give so someone might help me troubleshoot this a bit?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can select which OS will boot first by changing the boot order -- use efibootmgr from Ubuntu or bcdedit (I think) on the Windows side. Windows does like to keep putting itself first, so expect to have to do this every now and then. Selection at Power on should be available through the use of a function key (varies by machine, but sometimes the vendor splash screen indicates which key it is).  Take a look at the log files to hopefully get a clue why the crash occurred.